# How to export bash variable with value as string with hyphen?

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I'm running in a simple problem, cannot export a string value with hyphens in bash variables.
Here is what's happening:

.env

```
NAME_0=`Bruno - Souto`
NAME_1="Bruno - Souto"
NAME_2='Bruno - Souto'
```

export.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
set -xv

export $(cat .env | egrep -v "(^#.*|^$)" | xargs)

echo ${NAME_0} 
echo ${NAME_1} 
echo ${NAME_2}
```

output:

```
dev@dev:~/teste$ ./export.sh 

export $(cat .env | egrep -v "(^#.*|^$)" | xargs)
++ cat .env
++ xargs
++ egrep -v '(^#.*|^$)'
+ export 'NAME_0=`Bruno' - 'Souto`' NAME_1=Bruno - Souto NAME_2=Bruno - Souto
+ NAME_0='`Bruno'
./export.sh: line 4: export: `-': not a valid identifier
./export.sh: line 4: export: `Souto`': not a valid identifier
+ NAME_1=Bruno
./export.sh: line 4: export: `-': not a valid identifier
+ NAME_2=Bruno
./export.sh: line 4: export: `-': not a valid identifier

echo ${NAME_0} 
+ echo '`Bruno'
`Bruno
echo ${NAME_1} 
+ echo Bruno
Bruno
echo ${NAME_2} 
+ echo Bruno
Bruno
```

I DO NEED to export with 'xxx - xxx', doesn't matter how.
Any ideas?

thks

Comment: Can you please clarify what format you want your `.env` file to be? Is it shell assignments, `pam_env` format, `dotenv` format, or basic `key=value` pairs? These all look similar but need to be processed differently.

Comment: ^ That's a good point .. My answer assumes that `key=value` format is consistent.

Comment: I was just showing that any format is valid since it's working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First assignment (`NAME_0`) is invalid since the backticks imply that you want to run a command `Bruno` with arguments `-` and `Souto`.

Not sure why you don't just `source` the file and then manually `export` the variables (you already know the names - per the `echo` calls - so go ahead and `export`, too), eg:

```
$ source .env
-bash: Bruno: command not found       # result of using backticks in the NAME_0 assigment

$ typeset -p NAME_0 NAME_1 NAME_2
declare -- NAME_0=""
declare -- NAME_1="Bruno - Souto"
declare -- NAME_2="Bruno - Souto"

$ export NAME_0 NAME_1 NAME_2

$ typeset -p NAME_0 NAME_1 NAME_2
declare -x NAME_0=""
declare -x NAME_1="Bruno - Souto"
declare -x NAME_2="Bruno - Souto"
```

**NOTE:** `NAME_0` is empty due to the use of backticks in `.env`

Comment: You can use `set -a` before the `source` to automatically export them all

Answer (score 0):

With a single liner ..  I would skip the quotes in your `.env` file and read into your bash script *with* `export` ..

**.env**

```
NAME_0=Bruno - Souto
NAME_1=Bruno - Foo
NAME_2=Bruno - Bar
```

**test.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line; do LANG=C export "$line"; done <".env$1"
echo $NAME_0
echo $NAME_1
echo $NAME_2
```

**output**

```
$ bash test.sh
Bruno - Souto
Bruno - Foo
Bruno - Bar
```

**CLI**

```
~$ while read -r line; do LANG=C export "$line"; done <".env$1"
~$ echo $NAME_0
Bruno - Souto
~$ echo $NAME_1
Bruno - Foo
~$ echo $NAME_2
Bruno - Bar
```